# How to load updated variable in SwiftUI before view initiation?

Tags: swift, swiftui, mapkit

I am in the process of building a SwiftUI app but I am stuck with the initial value I am feeding a variable for initiation, and that it does not update when I load a view.

I have tried looking for some answers but nothing has worked for my code.

What I am trying to do is the following

1. I have a dataset with locations
2. I want to create a subset of these locations
3. I want to load the first location from the newly created subset

What I am stumbling with is that once I load the map for the first time it still maintains the initiation data and not the data from the subset

Any help is appreciated,
Daniel

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData
import MapKit
struct MainInterface: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    var initialPoint: Places = totalData[1]
    init() {
        let subset1 = Array(Set(totalData.filter({
            $0.Area == 1
        })))
        .prefix(3)
        let subset2 = Array(Set(totalData.filter({
            $0.Area == 2
        })))
        .prefix(3)
        levelSet = Array(subset1) + Array(subset2)
        self.initialPoint = levelSet[0]
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            SubView(initialPoint: $initialPoint)
        }
        .onAppear{
            //levelSet = Array(level1set) + Array(level2set)
            //self.initialPoint = levelSet[0]
        }
    }

}


import SwiftUI
import MapKit
struct SubView: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var initialPoint: Place
    let mapView = MKMapView()
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView {
        mapView.delegate = context.coordinator
        return mapView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ view: MKMapView, context: Context) {
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, MKMapViewDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
        var parent: SubView
        init(_ parent: SubView) {
            self.parent = parent
            super.init()
            self.parent.mapView.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: self.parent.initialPoint.Latitude, longitude: self.parent.initialPoint.Longitude), span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 10, longitudeDelta: 10)), animated: true)
        }
    }

    func mapViewDidChangeVisibleRegion(_ mapView: MKMapView) {
        parent.region = mapView.region
        parent.centerCoordinate = mapView.centerCoordinate
    }

}
```

Comment: You are encouraged to put the stuff in the `init` method into a view model and use the *observable* pattern. Otherwise `initialPoint` should be a `@State` property

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of issues going on here. First, `structs` can't normally be modified, so you can't modify their variables. This is why we have the `@State` property wrapper, among others, to allow the variables to be changed. However, simply changing the `initialPoint` variable to an `@State` one won't fix everything. In what code you have given, you seem to have stripped a lot of things out since you reference variables that are not initialized in your `MainInterface`, but what you have shown shouldn't compile as you are trying to pass a standard variable `initialPoint' to a binding just by adding a` $`. That needs a wrapped variable to use.

With what you have given us, I would init the struct this way:

```
struct MainInterface: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    // make this @State if you need to pass it to a binding.
    @State var initialPoint: Places 
    init(totalData: TotalData) { //I have know idea what the `Type` of totalData is
    //as you never defined it in the struct. Substitute its actual `Type` here.
        let subset1 = Array(Set(totalData.filter({
            $0.Area == 1
        })))
        .prefix(3)
        let subset2 = Array(Set(totalData.filter({
            $0.Area == 2
        })))
        .prefix(3)
        levelSet = Array(subset1) + Array(subset2)
        // This will initialize `initialPoint` as a State variable
        _initialPoint = State(initialValue: levelSet[0])
        // It seems to me that you have gone to a great deal of trouble to initialize
        // `initialPoint` to be the first element in the `subset1` array slice. I am not
        // sure what the point of creating your array slice as it is never used outside
        // of the `init()`
    }
```

I would start with [Apple's SwiftUI tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/SwiftUI) so that you start getting a feel. This exact situation is covered there, but you will have built up the how and why of it working.

Comment: This did not work for me :/ I will work on making a full code set available in order to replicate the issue.

Comment: We don't want the full code set. We want a  [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).